# C++: Instance of class in another class

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, visual-c++

I have a class named `Matrix` and a class named `NeuralNet`.
They look like this:

**Matrix.h**:

```
class Matrix
{
  public:
  double * matrix = nullptr;
  Matrix(int,int);
};
```

**Matrix.cpp**:

```
#include "Matrix.h"
Matrix::Matrix(int h,int w)
{
  matrix = new double[h*w];
};
```

My question is: "How can I use an instance of this class in the class `NeuralNet`?"
I tried :

**NeuralNet.h**:

```
class NeuralNet
{
  public:
  Matrix * ptr = nullptr;
  NeuralNet(int,int);
}
```

**NeuralNet.cpp**:

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include "NeuralNet.h"
NeuralNet::NeuralNet(int h,int w)
{
  ptr = new Matrix(h,w);
}
```

This doesn't work and I get the error:

> ```
>   Missing ';' before n'*'
> ```

Any type of help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: What if you add a `;` after the `}` for `class NeuralNet`?

Comment: `Matrix ` should be `matrix `

Comment: The semicolon you just added does absolutely nothing

Comment: Just a typo. Why should Matrix be matrix?

Comment: @AlessandroLegnani Because C++ is case-sensitive.

Comment: Make sure that `Matrix.h` does not include `NeuralNet.h`.

Comment: I know that so which "Matrix" should be written in lowercase?

Comment: `Matrix = new double[h*w];`

Comment: @drescherjm Why?

Comment: `Matrix` is the class when you want the variable `matrix`.

Comment: I meant the comment regarding the inclusion of NeuralNet.h in Matrix.h

Comment: Why use a pointer at all?

Comment: Use std::vector instead of raw pointers and new. Copy&paste error messages! Compile the code you show!

Comment: ***I meant the comment regarding the inclusion of NeuralNet.h in Matrix.h*** That would create a circular header dependency assuming that `NeuralNet.h` includes `Matrix.h`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In NeuralNet.h, you need to pre-declare Matrix:

```
class Matrix;
```

Or include it:

```
#include "Matrix.h"
```

Also, in Matrix.cpp,

```
Matrix::Matrix(int h,int w)
{
   Matrix = new double[h*w];
}
```

should be

```
Matrix::Matrix(int h,int w) :
   matrix( new double[h*w] )
{
}
```